# FTP upload and Dexterity folders

Tags: ftp, plone, dexterity

- Zope2-2.13.21
- Plone-4.3.2
- plone.dexterity-2.2.1
- plone.app.dexterity-2.0.11

Uploading a folder via FTP works but you get a broken object that leads you to this error in folder_contents:

ValueError: No object with id "" exists.

Even portaltop is broken:

2014-04-16 10:08:23 ERROR plone.app.viewletmanager rendering of plone.portaltop in plone.header fails: No object with id "" exists.

and when you delete the folder the catalog also complains:

2014-04-16 10:09:12 ERROR Zope.ZCatalog uncatalogObject unsuccessfully attempted to uncatalog an object with a uid of /Plone/avatars/.

I put some "print" into dexterity DAV/FTP factories:

https://github.com/plone/plone.dexterity/blob/master/plone/dexterity/filerepresentation.py#L391

https://github.com/plone/plone.dexterity/blob/master/plone/dexterity/filerepresentation.py#L408

but only the content in the folder pass into the latter.

Before I start digging more, is there a known issue w/ DX and FTP? I cannot find any reference.

Thanks for any pointers!

Full traceback:

```
2014-04-16 10:08:23 ERROR plone.app.viewletmanager rendering of plone.portaltop in plone.header fails: No object with id "" exists.
2014-04-16 10:08:23 ERROR Zope.SiteErrorLog 1397635703.390.776210033052 http://localhost:8180/Plone/folder_contents
Traceback (innermost last):
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 138, in publish
  Module ZPublisher.mapply, line 77, in mapply
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 48, in call_object
  Module wildcard.foldercontents.views, line 149, in __call__
  Module plone.app.content.browser.foldercontents, line 53, in __call__
  Module Products.Five.browser.metaconfigure, line 479, in __call__
  Module Products.Five.browser.pagetemplatefile, line 125, in __call__
  Module Products.Five.browser.pagetemplatefile, line 59, in __call__
  Module zope.pagetemplate.pagetemplate, line 132, in pt_render
   - Warning: Macro expansion failed
   - Warning: <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'>: widget
  Module zope.pagetemplate.pagetemplate, line 240, in __call__
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 271, in __call__
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 888, in do_useMacro
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 533, in do_optTag_tal
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 518, in do_optTag
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 513, in no_tag
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 954, in do_defineSlot
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 533, in do_optTag_tal
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 518, in do_optTag
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 513, in no_tag
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 858, in do_defineMacro
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 954, in do_defineSlot
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 533, in do_optTag_tal
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 518, in do_optTag
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 513, in no_tag
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 954, in do_defineSlot
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 533, in do_optTag_tal
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 518, in do_optTag
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 513, in no_tag
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 946, in do_defineSlot
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 533, in do_optTag_tal
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 518, in do_optTag
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 513, in no_tag
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 531, in do_optTag_tal
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 513, in no_tag
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 742, in do_insertStructure_tal
  Module Products.PageTemplates.Expressions, line 218, in evaluateStructure
  Module zope.tales.tales, line 696, in evaluate
   - URL: /home/simahawk/dev/plone/p4py27/buildout/eggs/wildcard.foldercontents-1.2.4-py2.7.egg/wildcard/foldercontents/folder_contents.pt
   - Line 151, Column 10
   - Expression: <PathExpr standard:u'view/contents_table'>
   - Names:
      {'args': (),
       'container': <PloneSite at /Plone>,
       'context': <PloneSite at /Plone>,
       'default': <object object at 0x7fcfbac174e0>,
       'here': <PloneSite at /Plone>,
       'loop': {},
       'nothing': None,
       'options': {},
       'repeat': <Products.PageTemplates.Expressions.SafeMapping object at 0x7fcfa846d418>,
       'request': <HTTPRequest, URL=http://localhost:8180/Plone/folder_contents>,
       'root': <Application at >,
       'template': <Products.Five.browser.pagetemplatefile.ViewPageTemplateFile object at 0x7fcfa08b17d0>,
       'traverse_subpath': [],
       'user': <PropertiedUser 'zopesimao'>,
       'view': <Products.Five.metaclass.SimpleViewClass from /home/simahawk/dev/plone/p4py27/buildout/eggs/wildcard.foldercontents-1.2.4-py2.7.egg/wildcard/foldercontents/folder_contents.pt object at 0x7fcfa08ac350>,
       'views': <Products.Five.browser.pagetemplatefile.ViewMapper object at 0x7fcfa08b1cd0>}
  Module zope.tales.expressions, line 217, in __call__
  Module Products.PageTemplates.Expressions, line 155, in _eval
  Module Products.PageTemplates.Expressions, line 117, in render
  Module wildcard.foldercontents.views, line 152, in contents_table
  Module wildcard.foldercontents.views, line 114, in __init__
  Module plone.app.content.browser.foldercontents, line 167, in folderitems
  Module Products.CMFCore.FSPythonScript, line 127, in __call__
  Module Shared.DC.Scripts.Bindings, line 322, in __call__
  Module Shared.DC.Scripts.Bindings, line 359, in _bindAndExec
  Module Products.PythonScripts.PythonScript, line 344, in _exec
  Module script, line 37, in getFolderContents
   - <FSPythonScript at /Plone/getFolderContents>
   - Line 37
  Module Products.CMFCore.FSPythonScript, line 127, in __call__
  Module Shared.DC.Scripts.Bindings, line 322, in __call__
  Module Shared.DC.Scripts.Bindings, line 359, in _bindAndExec
  Module Products.PythonScripts.PythonScript, line 344, in _exec
  Module script, line 115, in queryCatalog
   - <FSPythonScript at /Plone/portal_catalog/queryCatalog>
   - Line 115
  Module AccessControl.ZopeGuards, line 369, in guarded_apply
  Module AccessControl.ZopeGuards, line 391, in builtin_guarded_apply
  Module Products.CMFPlone.CatalogTool, line 393, in searchResults
  Module Products.ZCatalog.ZCatalog, line 604, in searchResults
  Module Products.ZCatalog.Catalog, line 907, in searchResults
  Module Products.ZCatalog.Catalog, line 656, in search
  Module Products.ZCatalog.Catalog, line 676, in sortResults
  Module plone.app.folder.nogopip, line 104, in documentToKeyMap
  Module plone.folder.ordered, line 102, in getObjectPosition
  Module plone.folder.default, line 128, in getObjectPosition
ValueError: No object with id "" exists.
2014-04-16 10:08:23 ERROR plone.app.viewletmanager rendering of plone.portaltop in plone.header fails: No object with id "" exists.
2014-04-16 10:09:12 ERROR Zope.ZCatalog uncatalogObject unsuccessfully attempted to uncatalog an object with a uid of /Plone/avatars/.
2014-04-16 10:08:23 ERROR plone.app.viewletmanager rendering of plone.portaltop in plone.header fails: No object with id "" exists.
2014-04-16 10:08:23 ERROR Zope.SiteErrorLog 1397635703.390.776210033052 http://localhost:8180/Plone/folder_contents
Traceback (innermost last):
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 138, in publish
  Module ZPublisher.mapply, line 77, in mapply
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 48, in call_object
  Module wildcard.foldercontents.views, line 149, in __call__
  Module plone.app.content.browser.foldercontents, line 53, in __call__
  Module Products.Five.browser.metaconfigure, line 479, in __call__
  Module Products.Five.browser.pagetemplatefile, line 125, in __call__
  Module Products.Five.browser.pagetemplatefile, line 59, in __call__
  Module zope.pagetemplate.pagetemplate, line 132, in pt_render
   - Warning: Macro expansion failed
   - Warning: <type 'exceptions.AttributeError'>: widget
  Module zope.pagetemplate.pagetemplate, line 240, in __call__
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 271, in __call__
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 888, in do_useMacro
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 533, in do_optTag_tal
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 518, in do_optTag
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 513, in no_tag
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 954, in do_defineSlot
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 533, in do_optTag_tal
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 518, in do_optTag
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 513, in no_tag
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 858, in do_defineMacro
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 954, in do_defineSlot
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 533, in do_optTag_tal
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 518, in do_optTag
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 513, in no_tag
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 954, in do_defineSlot
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 533, in do_optTag_tal
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 518, in do_optTag
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 513, in no_tag
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 946, in do_defineSlot
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 533, in do_optTag_tal
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 518, in do_optTag
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 513, in no_tag
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 531, in do_optTag_tal
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 513, in no_tag
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 343, in interpret
  Module zope.tal.talinterpreter, line 742, in do_insertStructure_tal
  Module Products.PageTemplates.Expressions, line 218, in evaluateStructure
  Module zope.tales.tales, line 696, in evaluate
   - URL: /home/simahawk/dev/plone/p4py27/buildout/eggs/wildcard.foldercontents-1.2.4-py2.7.egg/wildcard/foldercontents/folder_contents.pt
   - Line 151, Column 10
   - Expression: <PathExpr standard:u'view/contents_table'>
   - Names:
      {'args': (),
       'container': <PloneSite at /Plone>,
       'context': <PloneSite at /Plone>,
       'default': <object object at 0x7fcfbac174e0>,
       'here': <PloneSite at /Plone>,
       'loop': {},
       'nothing': None,
       'options': {},
       'repeat': <Products.PageTemplates.Expressions.SafeMapping object at 0x7fcfa846d418>,
       'request': <HTTPRequest, URL=http://localhost:8180/Plone/folder_contents>,
       'root': <Application at >,
       'template': <Products.Five.browser.pagetemplatefile.ViewPageTemplateFile object at 0x7fcfa08b17d0>,
       'traverse_subpath': [],
       'user': <PropertiedUser 'zopesimao'>,
       'view': <Products.Five.metaclass.SimpleViewClass from /home/simahawk/dev/plone/p4py27/buildout/eggs/wildcard.foldercontents-1.2.4-py2.7.egg/wildcard/foldercontents/folder_contents.pt object at 0x7fcfa08ac350>,
       'views': <Products.Five.browser.pagetemplatefile.ViewMapper object at 0x7fcfa08b1cd0>}
  Module zope.tales.expressions, line 217, in __call__
  Module Products.PageTemplates.Expressions, line 155, in _eval
  Module Products.PageTemplates.Expressions, line 117, in render
  Module wildcard.foldercontents.views, line 152, in contents_table
  Module wildcard.foldercontents.views, line 114, in __init__
  Module plone.app.content.browser.foldercontents, line 167, in folderitems
  Module Products.CMFCore.FSPythonScript, line 127, in __call__
  Module Shared.DC.Scripts.Bindings, line 322, in __call__
  Module Shared.DC.Scripts.Bindings, line 359, in _bindAndExec
  Module Products.PythonScripts.PythonScript, line 344, in _exec
  Module script, line 37, in getFolderContents
   - <FSPythonScript at /Plone/getFolderContents>
   - Line 37
  Module Products.CMFCore.FSPythonScript, line 127, in __call__
  Module Shared.DC.Scripts.Bindings, line 322, in __call__
  Module Shared.DC.Scripts.Bindings, line 359, in _bindAndExec
  Module Products.PythonScripts.PythonScript, line 344, in _exec
  Module script, line 115, in queryCatalog
   - <FSPythonScript at /Plone/portal_catalog/queryCatalog>
   - Line 115
  Module AccessControl.ZopeGuards, line 369, in guarded_apply
  Module AccessControl.ZopeGuards, line 391, in builtin_guarded_apply
  Module Products.CMFPlone.CatalogTool, line 393, in searchResults
  Module Products.ZCatalog.ZCatalog, line 604, in searchResults
  Module Products.ZCatalog.Catalog, line 907, in searchResults
  Module Products.ZCatalog.Catalog, line 656, in search
  Module Products.ZCatalog.Catalog, line 676, in sortResults
  Module plone.app.folder.nogopip, line 104, in documentToKeyMap
  Module plone.folder.ordered, line 102, in getObjectPosition
  Module plone.folder.default, line 128, in getObjectPosition
ValueError: No object with id "" exists.
2014-04-16 10:08:23 ERROR plone.app.viewletmanager rendering of plone.portaltop in plone.header fails: No object with id "" exists.
2014-04-16 10:09:12 ERROR Zope.ZCatalog uncatalogObject unsuccessfully attempted to uncatalog an object with a uid of /Plone/avatars/.
```